# install4j- read license value instead of connection to the license server

Tags: install4j

our CI agent connect to server where install4j process is running.
It connects succesfully and reads the license.

Now we need to implement CI pipeline on the agent that does not and will not have connection to license server.
So for that reason I wanted to read the license value and set the license value, instead of connecting to the server. Can we just read the value of the `license.txt` file for that purpose?

License is something like in this format (of course I will not provide real value here):

```
B-20-1-TEST_COMP_TEST#12345678911-aabbccddxn7w
```

But, when I try to set this value locally from my machine, instead of the connection to the server to use this raw value I am getting info:
"**This license cannot be used for this version of install4j**".

How is this possible? Since in the same time if we try to connect from the client to the server (instead of entering the licence) then connection pass.

Please assist, I do not have experience with install4j. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now we need to implement CI pipeline on the agent that does not and will not
> have connection to license server. So for that reason I wanted to read the
> license value and set the license value, instead of connecting to the server.
> Can we just read the value of the license.txt file for that purpose?

No, that is not possible. Floating license keys cannot be used directly with the client, they only work with the floating license server.

If you do not have connectivity to the floating license server, you need a build-only license key:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/select?target=command_line

Comment: I suppose that GitHub action doesn't support floating license keys https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-up-install4j as they have for the license segment "`license: ${{ secrets.INSTALL4J_LICENSE }}`" which means only the key value can be entered and not the connection to the server. Am I right, if you are familiar with this one?

Comment: The "license key" for connecting to a floating license server has the format "FLOAT:server" where you replace "server" with the IP address or the host name of the license server. However, you would have to expose the license server on the internet, only do that with encryption enabled.